# How to differentiate docker containers in stackdriver logging?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver, centralized-logging

I have a VM in GCE with docker installed. There I run containers using the [Google Cloud Logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/gcplogs/). I can see the logs in stackdrive logging. However, i can't easily browse between logs of different containers. All the containers' logs get indexed under the `logName` `projects/my-project/logs/gcplogs-docker-driver`

Is there any way to have fields on the "Log Fields" pane on the left that would allow me to easily filter by container? It seems that the `logName` in the gcplogs-docker-driver is hardcoded, so that's not possible to modify. I tried to "add field to log fields pane" using `jsonPayload.container.name` but it looks like any field inside `jsonPayload` cannot be used in the log fields pane, it shows "Value not present"

[image]

I also tried adding labels as gcplogs options but they get sent under the `jsonPayload` as well so same problem as with the container name

Comment: Have you tried with ```jsonPayload.container.imageName="hello-world"```?

Comment: you mean in the search query? if so, yes, but having to type it is not ideal. i have a lot of containers sometimes with random names. That's why I was trying to find a way to do it with the (left) Log Fields pane, which is populated with the available values

Comment: I have created a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/196021630) on your behalf because it may be interesting to add that feature. Please take into account that it's not certain to be feasible and there is not an estimated time of arrival for these types of possible updates.

Answer (score 0):

Also, it is resolved for me as gcplogs-driver also includes the metadata of the container then you just have to specify the container name in stackdriver query.

resource.type="gce_instance" "my_container"
[Image with query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmIcM.png)